# gradle set build order on android multi project

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradlew

There are AAR libraries that contain jni libraries and APKs that contain AAR libraries.

I would like to build their gradle builds sequentially as shown below.

Project
├─app
├─jni_library
└─aar_library

1. jni library build
2. aar library build include 1
3. apk build include 2

Gradle version is 6.1.1
Android gradle plugin version is 4.0.

We tried the solution below to do this, but there was a phenomenon such as a debug build working when building a release.

build.gradle (:app)

```
debug {
preBuild.dependsOn("aar_library:assembleDebug")
    }

release {
preBuild.dependsOn("aar_library:assembleDebug")
    }
```

build.gradle (:library1)

```
debug {
preBuild.dependsOn("jni_library:assembleDebug")
    }

release {
preBuild.dependsOn("jni_library:assembleDebug")
    }
```